# Using nHibernate 3.x with Jet driver (Microsoft Access)

Tags: nhibernate, ms-access, jet

I'm working on an nHibernate project that uses an Access Database as the datasource (unfortunately). I'm having issues getting it working because I can't find a Jet driver that supports nHibernate 3.x.

I've downloaded the source from the trunk and compiled it, but it turns out it is still for nHibernate 2.x. Are there any ideas on where to find a new version, or how to get the older one to work with nHibernate 3.x?

Comment: What is the reason why you are restricted to using 3.x instead of just using 2.x (since your Jet driver already supports 2.x)?

Comment: There were features in NH 3.x I needed to use that were not present in NH 2.x. I can't recall what they were now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to rebuild [NHibernate.JetDriver](https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.JetDriver/) agains NHibernate 3 or just use [this](http://coderead.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/nhibernate-jet-driver/)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response - but I did both of the things you suggested. I did the first part by using the pre-compiled version at the link you showed. After a while, I wanted to upgrade to FNH and found that I had to rebuild the jet driver against the same version of NH that FNH was for.

Thanks!